# Why does Unanswered show Answered questions?

Tags: bug, unanswered-questions, navigation

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Unexpected Results From Clicking The Unanswered Button](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4146/unexpected-results-from-clicking-the-unanswered-button)

When I click 'Unanswered' in the menubar, I get a list of questions, all of which have been answered. Does it just mean there's no *accepted* answer? If so, can we make that more obvious? Can we get some way of finding *really* unanswered questions?

Comment: Dupe: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4146/

Comment: see also: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/675

Comment: If you want to filter any page (unanswered, home, questions, etc) down to 0 answers, I've create a greasemonkey script that does that and a few more things : http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11096/filter-questions-greasemonkey-script

Comment: Many apologies for the dupe. Didn't find anything dupe-ish in the suggestions based on the question title.

Answer (score 1):

"Unanswered" in this case means that none of the answers for the question have been upvoted, and none of the answers have been accepted - in other words, none of the answers supplied for the question helped the asker answer it at all.