# Unanswered questions view shows answered questions

Tags: support, unanswered-questions

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Unexpected Results From Clicking The Unanswered Button](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4146/unexpected-results-from-clicking-the-unanswered-button)

If I select a tag, say Java, then hit the "unanswered" button to show all the unanswered questions, then scroll to a page at the end (the last page for instance) I get a load of questions that have already been answered.

My guess is that the label probably means that there's no accepted answer to the question rather than there's no answers at all, but this seems a bit confusing to me.

Comment: Duplicate to: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4146/unexpected-results-from-clicking-the-unanswered-button, http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11568/why-does-unanswered-show-answered-questions. As elaborated, unaccepted also includes questions that have no positively scored answers, not just ones that lack answers entirely.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unanswered questions are defined as not having an answer with a positive score / an accepted answer. You're probably seeing 0-scoring unaccepted answers.

Comment: Ah, that makes sense. Is there a way to get a list of all the questions that haven't got any answer at all?

Comment: @berry120: Try http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=answers%3A0 (or type `answers:0` into the search box at the upper right corner)

Comment: Nice one, that's exactly what I was after. Thanks!

Comment: or just click the "no answers" tab...