# Stackoverflow Bug: View Last Page of Unanswered question and all questions are answered one

Tags: bug, unanswered-questions

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Unexpected Results From Clicking The Unanswered Button](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4146/unexpected-results-from-clicking-the-unanswered-button)

GO to stackoverflow:

Select UnAnswered Questions

Go to the last page:

[Stackoverflow Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions?page=13998&sort=unanswered)

And you will find all the questions has answers in it. Strange

Comment: The "Unanswered" tab shows questions with no upvoted answers

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not a bug. None of the answers has any upvotes:

> [image]

(The sort of the unanswered questions list look weird - couldn't quite figure it out but it's not relevant to this question)