# Change of 'Unanswered' to 'Unresolved' for Meta

Tags: discussion, feature-request, unanswered-questions, tabs

I think that the 'Unanswered' tab should be name-changed to 'Unresolved', since the name does not reflect the contents.  When I first joined SE, I was very puzzled as to why there were *answered* questions in the tab named '**Un**answered.'  This makes it appear that the 'No answers' sub-tab is the same as the 'Unanswered' tab.  I believe this works much better, *because it accurately describes the contents of the tab.*  **Note: I only propose that  this happen on Meta, regarding @Pandya's comment.  I agree.  This works much better for tags such as [discussion](/questions/tagged/discussion).**

This is a recognised issue in the linked question below.  And as @rlb.usa mentions [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4146/unexpected-results-from-clicking-the-unanswered-button?noredirect=1&lq=1), this is a problem on many sites (i.e. Super User)

Almost *always* when people have to include the phrase "unanswered questions" on a meta they almost *always* have to put the parenthesis *no questions with upvoted or accepted answers* such as [here,](https://ell.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4586/lets-bring-down-the-number-of-unanswered-questions?cb=1) for example.

**Not** a duplicate of [Why does the "Unanswered Questions" tab show questions that have answers?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/18870/why-does-the-unanswered-questions-tab-show-questions-that-have-answers), because this is a [feature-request](/questions/tagged/feature-request).

**EDIT:** On the above-linked question, @EBGreen has also suggested this, with 40 upvotes.  Thankfully, @Adam Davis notes:

> It's an ongoing issue that may have a better solution eventually, but it's the best we have now. We don't want to drop questions off the unanswered tab just because they have one bad answer, nor do we want to wait until an accepted answer is chosen. So - if all the answers are 0 it's unanswered.

But with an 'Unresolved' tab, this issue doesn't apply, only an accurate name-change takes place.

**EDIT 2**: I agree with @Pandya's solution, to have 'unresolved' for most Meta tags and 'unanswered' for questions.

Comment: "Unaccepted" would also not reflect the contents of the tab, because ["accepted answer"](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/274942) means something completely different. There's definitely . . . er . . . not an obvious adjective to use.

Comment: @HDE226868  Yes, I see this now.

Comment: The term/word "unsolved" is suitable for issue/problem whereas "unanswered" is suitable for questions I think.

Comment: @Mari-LouA Thanks; fixed.

Comment: @Pandya Agreed; added into post.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Nothing is perfect in life, more so in the English language, nevertheless I shall attempt to defend "unanswered" and argue that the term is appropriate, it has its flaws but it is the best solution *for* Stack Exchange's purposes.

If I click on the sandwich menu and visit the page [unanswered questions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/unanswered), here on Meta, the vast majority of posts do not have any "answers". There is also a preface at the top of the page which says

> **11,385 questions with no upvoted or accepted answers**
>
> [image]

The explanation is written in good concise English, clear and unequivocal. The paradoxical situation the OP speaks of “ I was very puzzled as to why there were answered questions in the tab named '**Un**answered'” should have been dispelled by that brief clarification.

In stark contrast, if we click on **Questions** and then on the **[unanswered](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions?sort=unanswered)** tab, no clarifying message is supplied.

> [image]

Objectively this is counter-intuitive but there is a simple fix. The same message should be displayed on *both* pages so as to eliminate, as far as possible, ambiguity and confusion.

Let's now talk about semantics, hopefully I'll be able to illustrate why "unresolved" opens its own separate can of worms.

1. Can a **Feature Request** be *resolved*?

According to the [Longman's dictionary](https://www.ldoceonline.com/dictionary/resolve), *problems*, *disputes*, *conflicts*, *issues*, *situations* and *matters* are **resolved** or stay *[**unresolved**](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/unresolved)* whereas *problems*, *cases*, *riddles*, and *mysteries* are either solved or *[unsolved](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/unsolved)*. On the other hand, ***[requests](https://www.ldoceonline.com/dictionary/request)*** are *responded to*, *approved*, *accepted*, *granted* or they can be *refused*, *rejected*, *turned down* and *ignored*. In other words, a *request* is not answered.

In fact, on the first page there is a well-supported *[feature request](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/266693/could-mods-have-add-comments-to-chat-to-supplement-move-comments-to-chat)* that has received four "answers", none of which have a positive score. I don't have 10K rep, so it's even possible that there are also deleted "answers". Technically, SE could label those pages *unapproved* or *ungranted*, but then we would have users pointing out that topics of [discussion](/questions/tagged/discussion) on Meta cannot be *approved* or *granted*. Discussions can lead to solutions but **many also end up *unresolved*** despite receiving three or more upvoted posts, basically people just going round and round in circles and rarely meeting in the middle with little or no agreement reached.

> Questions that may not necessarily have a clear-cut right or wrong answer and are often subjective. If your question isn't a bug report, feature request, or request for assistance, or question with a concrete answer, it's probably a discussion.

How many more questions from the 88,979 questions posted until today would MSE have to add to that *unanswered* previously mentioned?

### Leaving aside Meta, let's move onto the 174 sites that currently populate the Stack Exchange network.

The slogan that greets first time visitors is the following [emphasis in **bold** mine]

> Stack Exchange network consists of 175 **Q&A** communities including Stack Overflow, the largest, most trusted online community for developers to learn, share their knowledge, and build their careers.

Then we have the following tagline [emphasis in bold *not* mine]

> **The right answer. Right on top.**
>   Experts like you can vote on posts, so the most helpful **answers** [emphasis mine] are easy to find.

The message is all about one question with ***top answers***. The noun "answer" is used in the manifesto, not *resolution*, *solution*, *result*, or *elucidation*. Therefore, it makes perfect marketing sense to use the terms *answered* and *unanswered* repeatedly and throughout the entire network. **Simplicity is always best**

Last but not least, an *answer* is not only a post submitted by an ‘expert’ but it can also offer the solution to a problem posed by the questioner.

Comment: I disagree with this.  A feature request can be 'resolved.'  [On thesaurus.com,](https://www.thesaurus.com/browse/resolved) the second synonym for resolved is 'answer[ed]'.   Your so-called problematic distinction between these two words I see as of minimal importance.

Comment: @Lordology *the second synonym for resolved is 'answer[ed]'* Are you now saying that the two terms are equivalent? Then why bother changing, if they mean the same? Furthermore, a request is not normally answered, it is granted or approved.

Comment: No, I don't see them as the same, I just don't agree with your specified problem.  And I know there are feature-requests on Meta, but on 173 other SE sites (not including their metas) they are questions.  If needed, this change might be applied to Meta re your discussion tag point.